# Changing font tracking in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, fonts, tracking

I'm doing some text rendering in Cocoa using NSAttributedString, and setting the font and underline properties, etc.  However, I can't figure out how I can change the text's tracking.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think font tracking is an exposed property for text layout with attributed strings.

You could perhaps use the available **expansion** attribute on whitespace, and manually insert whitespace characters with scaling factors to influence their width, but I expect that would be a fiddly hack for anything other than trivial cases.

The only other route I can think of is to use your own custom attributes along with an `NSLayoutManager` subclass. The cocoa text system is extremely flexible, but with that flexibility comes a greater degree of complexity.

Answer (score -1):

My solution so far has simply been to use the kerning attribute, as tracking and kerning are similar.  Is there any better solution?